# Output full path of file being compiled in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have a C++ project with several files having the same name (located in different directories). When I compile, the output looks something like this:
[image]

As you can see, I can't identify the file currently being compiled by that output since there are multiple files called for example `Edge.ixx`. How can I make Visual Studio output the full path of the file being compiled. Showing the `Include` path as specified in the `.vcxproj` file would make most sense to me, but absolute path would also be fine.

I already have `Use Full Paths` (`/FC`) enabled:
[image]

Comment: Why do you need it? It will show a full path if error occurs.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you enable /FC?

Comment: @273K: I'd like to verify which files are recompiled when I make certain changes so I can try to optimize build times.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT: `/FC` is already enabled.

Comment: Use the tool include-what-you-use for such purposes.

Comment: I mean did the project build successfully? Can you provide build error messages?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT: Everything builds fine :) On compiler errors, the full path is shown.